# Is this animation CSS only, or does it need JS as well?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

On [this page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/thankyou.html?brand=RLNS&statcb=1) for downloading Google Chrome, if you hover you mouse over the Chrome logo, a radial animation is played. Console shows the `img` has the following in-line style:

```
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-gradient(radial, 17 17, 123, 17 17, 138, from(rgb(0, 0, 0)), color-stop(0.5, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), to(rgb(0, 0, 0)));
```

I doubt the animation is the result of the style (or at least there should be other code contributing to it). The reasons I think so are:

- There is no time component for key-framing in the style,
- It is applied to the element directly and not through a `:hover` psudo selector,
- When I apply the same style to images on other pages (in console), no animation is added.

So, how is it implemented?

Comment: If you visit the page to check, be aware that a download of `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` starts automatically, which you may want to cancel (or not!)

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! It would be nice if you could expand that into an answer in which you also include the css-only solution.

Comment: Actually I was wrong... Browsers still don't animate `radial-gradient`... So you need to do it though js, like they did, or through SMIL.

Comment: @Kaiido, You was not wrong.

Comment: @KoshVery well I thought it was now possible to animate radial-gradients, and I was wrong about that. Yes, it can be achieved in many non-js ways, but no, animating a mask-image:radial-gradient only through CSS is still not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pure CSS solution:

```css
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -3.335em;
  width: 8em;
  height: 8em;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  border-radius: 55%;
  background: radial-gradient(transparent 1em, rgba(255, 255, 255, .9) 2em, transparent 3em);
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

div:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  font: 400 4rem/2 sans-serif;
  color: #777;
  overflow:hidden;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  width: .65em;
  height: .65em;
  margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
  border: solid .35em;
  border-radius: 55%;
  border-color: #e42 #777 #3b5 #fb0;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 .08em #fff;
  background:#59f content-box;
}
```

```html
<div>chronic</div>
```